# fixesd point of strictly monotonic continuous function

Tags: fixed-points

Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic continous real valued function defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)<a$ and $f(b)>b$. Then, which one of the following is true?

a) There exists exactly one $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$

b) There exist exactly two points $c_1,c_2 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c_i)=c_i$ for $i=1,2$

c)There is no  $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$

d)There exist infinitely many points  $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=c$

given:  $f(a)<a$   and $f(b)>b$
implies $f(-a)>-a$
hence $f(b)-f(a)>b-a   \implies\frac {f(b)-f(a)} {b-a} \gt {1}$

By Lagrange Mean value theorem there exist $c\in(a,b)$ such that $\frac {f(b)-f(a)} {b-a} =f'(c)$

hence $f'(c)>1$ that is given function is strictly increasing at $c$.

so what we can conclude from this?